# 改行コードを一括変換したい

Tags: windows, atom-editor

数百ものファイルのほとんどが改行コードCRLFで、このままではlintにはじかれてしまいます。
(git configを忘れたためです。もう一度clone、は控えたい。)
一括でLFに変換したいのですが、いい方法はないでしょうか。
できればAtomで行いたいです。
試した方法:

- INASOFTさんの改行コード変換 (ファイルが0バイトになった)
- 同・改行コード変換Lite (サブフォルダを探索しない)
- AtomのProject Findで、regexをONにし`\r\n`で検索 (No Result)
- AtomのConvert Line Encodings To パッケージ (一括処理できない)

環境: Windows 7 HomePremium 64bit sp1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

結局cygwin経由でdos2unixを動かすことにしました。(`dos2unix ./*/*/*`など)
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

PowerShellの`Get-String`で`sed`相当の操作ができるようなので、再帰的に置換してみてはいかがでしょうか？

`Get-Content .\foo.txt | % { $_ -replace "\r\n","\n" }`
参考：https://qiita.com/cd01/items/da9a36582372e7d0a7f6#sed